# How to ORDER BY typical software release versions like X.Y.Z?

Tags: postgresql, order-by, sorting, natural-sort

Given a "SoftwareReleases" table:

```
| id | version |
|  1 | 0.9     |
|  2 | 1.0     |
|  3 | 0.9.1   |
|  4 | 1.1     |
|  5 | 0.9.9   |
|  6 | 0.9.10  |
```

How do I produce this output?

```
| id | version |
|  1 | 0.9     |
|  3 | 0.9.1   |
|  5 | 0.9.9   |
|  6 | 0.9.10  |
|  2 | 1.0     |
|  4 | 1.1     |
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

To produce your desired output:

```
SELECT id, version
FROM   versions
ORDER  BY string_to_array(version, '.')::int[];
```

Cast the whole `text` array to an `integer` array (to sort `9` before `10`) and `ORDER BY` that.
This is the same as ordering by each of the elements.
Shorter arrays come before longer ones with an equivalent leading part.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=951e0f2d0a787564eb352cedec116d16)*
<sub>Old [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/c9acb/4)</sub>

Comment: This is great. Somehow, this sorts missing values correctly, without having to specify the order of nulls: (1.6.9 -> 1.7 -> 1.7.1), rather than (1.6.9 -> 1.7.1 -> 1.7). Accepting this one.

Comment: If you're dealing with Maven versions or versions that may contain non-numeric characters, you can remove the non-numeric characters first: `string_to_array(regexp_replace(version, '[^0-9.]', '', 'g'), '.')::int[]`

Comment: I use this to find the max version and it works great
`SELECT max(string_to_array(build_version, '.')::int[]`

Answer (score 6):

```
select id,
       name, 
       v[1] as major_version,
       v[2] as minor_version,
       v[3] as patch_level
from (
   select id, 
          name, 
          string_to_array(version, '.') as v
   from versions
) t
order by v[1]::int desc, v[2]::int desc, v[3]::int desc;
```

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/c9acb/1

If you expect more elements in the version string, just use more array indexes. If the index does not exist, the result will be null (e.g. `v[10]` will return `null`)

Comment: Do you need to convert these to numbers? Otherwise I would expect `10` to be between `1` and `2`.

Comment: This is confirmed by your fiddle...

Comment: Deleting mine in favor of this. string_to_array is much simpler than regex.

Comment: @JNK: that is what the `v[1]::int` is about. It casts the string to an integer.

Comment: The only change I'd make to your SQL is the order by. I suggest taking out desc and that will create the result set @Chris Betti is looking for.

Answer (score 5):

create extension semver;

select id, version from SoftwareReleases order by version::semver;

http://www.pgxn.org/dist/semver/doc/semver.html

Comment: This is the correct answer as the selected one doesn't cope well with full semver like alpha release etc...